# Validate a field based on outcome of other field validations in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have the following `serializers.py` file:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class SampleSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=False,required=True)
    initials = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=False,required=True)

    def validate_initials(self,data):
        if len(data) > 10:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Length of initials is too long")
```

I want to prevent `validate_initials()` from being called unless `name` has been provided. In other words only if the validation for `name` passes must it validate `initials`.

How do i achieve such a hierarchy in serializer validation?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this in the [**`.validate(…)`** method [drf-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#optional-fields). This will run when validating individual fields was done succesfully:

```
class SampleSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=False,required=True)
    initials = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=False,required=True)

    def validate(self,data):
        if len(data['initials']) > 10:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Length of initials is too long')
        return super().validate(data)
```

You can also include more complicated validation where you check for example if two fields together satisfy a certain constraint.